# Exception while calling stored procedure :Bigger type length than Maximum

Tags: oracle9i, jdbc, sqlexception, weblogic8.x

HI I am getting this exception when I am calling any stored procedure from my J2EE app.

> Exception while calling stored procedure :Bigger type length than Maximum

I am having Oracle 9.1.0.7, JDK1.4 and using ojdbc14.jar running on Weblogic 8.1

Please advise what could be the root cause ?

Below is the manifest of my ojdbc14.jar

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>   Implementation-Version: "Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.1.0.2.0"
>   Specification-Title:    "Oracle JDBC driver classes for use with JDK1.4"
>   Specification-Version:  "Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.1.0.2.0"
>   Implementation-Title:   "ojdbc14.jar"
>   Created-By: 1.2.2 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
>   Implementation-Time:    "Wed Jan 21 00:48:12 2004"
>   Implementation-Vendor:  "Oracle Corporation"
>   Specification-Vendor:   "Oracle Corporation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a driver bug.  Your version is already 6 years old.  Download the latest and greatest [from here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_10201.html).

Answer (score 1):

See this [post](http://michaelzanussi.com/?p=646) for a possible workaround.

For possible causes, see this [thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=688414):

> There are bugs in different versions
>   of the drivers and different versions
>   of the database; most of them are
>   fixed in later versions.
>
> For example, bugs produce the "Bigger
>   type length than maximum" in Oracle
>   database 8.1.7.2 or 9.0.1.1 for
>   certain very specific operations using
>   DB links; upgrading to 8.1.7.3 or
>   8.1.7.4 or 9.0.1.2 resolves those problems.
>
> For example, bugs produce the "Bigger
>   type length than maximum" in Oracle
>   database 10.1.0.2 and 10.1.0.3 for
>   certain very specific operations
>   involving NLS characters; upgrading to
>   10.1.0.4 pr 10.2.0.1 resolves those problems.
>
> For example, the 8.1.6 classes12.zip
>   had such a bug on certain operation
>   with databases in a UNICODE character
>   set, that was fixed in the 8.1.7.4
>   driver.
>
> If you have an Oracle support
>   contract, you can find out this
>   information on the Oracle support
>   site; metalink.oracle.com If not,
>   download the latest versions of the
>   drivers and pray...

Answer (score 0):

i downloaded the latest driver and now much better - now that all the referenced locations are updated

Answer (score 0):

Another option than you can consider is review your query parameters, specially setFetchSize, if its too high this error is returned.

java.sql.SQLException: Bigger type length than Maximum

There is a maximun size depending on the database in my case 64kb (Oracle) my highest value have to be 65535

Reference document:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28621